# Add a URL to the caption parameter when posting to Facebook via SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm currently using code that is virtually identical to the example from [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/) for posting to a user's wall using **presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession**.

Is there a way to **associate a URL** with the "caption" parameter that gets sent up with the post, or can it only be displayed as static text?

```
- (IBAction)publishButtonAction:(id)sender {
    // Put together the dialog parameters
    NSMutableDictionary *params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",

     //----------------------------------------------------
     // can we add a URL for the caption parameter here?
     @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption", 
     //----------------------------------------------------

     @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
     @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
     @"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
     nil];

    // Invoke the dialog
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         // handle the result...
    }];
}
```

The documentation does not seem to indicate a way to do this, but just wanted to check and see if maybe I was missing a detail that was not readily apparent from the docs.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the documentation on the following pages:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

These pages contain information regarding the posting mechanism and the legal parameters that one can pass, whether using the presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession method or using the Graph API directly (using /PROFILE_ID/feed). Here are the definitions present in those docs:

- The link is defined as "the link attached to this post".
- The caption is defined as "The caption of the link (appears beneath the link name). If not specified, this field is automatically populated with the URL of the link".

This suggests that the caption cannot be really used like an anchor tag with text and a URL associated with it, but it will get populated with the textual representation of a link by displaying the URL in the caption if a caption is not supplied.

Therefore, I've come to the conclusion that the answer is, in fact, no... you can't attach a URL to a caption as you might an HTML anchor tag.

*NOTE: If anyone finds different please feel free to post answers and comments. I'd really like to be shown to be wrong on this, actually, since I have a client who would really like to customize the caption with a URL that is different than the URL supplied with the "link" parameter.*